# Using || in arguments in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I just saw this code:

```
method_name(ARGV.shift || "somefile.txt")
```

which basically should first evalute `ARGV[0]` and if it doesn't exist then read from "somefile.txt".

My question was, can the `&&` operator be also used here, and in what situations?

Also, does this concept of "passing this or this argument" to a method in Ruby have a name?

Comment: The `&&` operator will make the statement `if ARGV.shift exists and "somefile.txt" exists produce "somefile.txt" else false` whereas your current statement can be read as `if ARGV.shift exists produce ARGV.shift else produce "somefile.txt"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer, `logical operators` are going to return one of its **operands** based on if it's [*`truthy`* or *`falsey`*](https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362). In practice, nearly everything in Ruby will evaluate to `true` **except** `false` or `nil`.

Examples:

`expr1 || expr2` will return (`expr1` **if not** *`falsey`*) or (`expr2`)
**In other words**, the first *`truthy`* value or the final operand,

`expr1 && expr2` will return (`expr1` **if** *`falsey`*) or (`expr2`).
**In other words**, the first *`falsey`* value or the final operand.

As for an actual use case, a similar example would be:
Using the `&&` operator to check for a flag in `ARGV` then passing the file name.

```
method_name(ARGV.include?('-w') && "write_file.txt")
```

It should be noted that this is probably not a widely accepted practice. *(see comments)*

However, preferring a user supplied value over a default value, by using `||`, in this manner would be.

Comment: "...probably not an acceptable practice" -- *WHAT* isn't acceptable, using `||` or `&&`? Using `ARGV.shift && 'somefile.txt'` in a parameter list would be a maintenance problem at least and more likely an outright bug. Using `||` in this context is very terse, but it's a lot more common, especially in C/C++ and Perl, so the chances of it being understood are better, somewhat reducing the maintenance problem. `||` is also more likely to return an understandable/expected value, reducing the "buginess" likelihood.

Comment: Sorry, I meant using logical AND (`&&`). My wording is pretty ambiguous, again sorry. But, it isn't *acceptable* for the exact reason you described. Not because `&&` in that situation doesn't work, but because it's not commonly used by the programming community at large.

Answer (score 2):

If `&&` is used, then the argument would be `nil` when there is no `ARGV[0]` and `"somefile.txt"` when there is `ARGV[0]`. Note that elements of `ARGV`, if any, would be strings, so there is no possibility of `ARGV[0]` being `nil` or `false` when there is an element passed.

Generally, `||` and `&&` are called "(short circuit) disjunction" and "(short circuit) conjunction", respectively.

A typical use case of `||` is to provide a default value:

```
foo = potentially_falesy_value || default
```

A typical use case of `&&` is to provide a value that depends on the truthness of another value:

```
foo = hash[:bar] && hash[:bar][:baz]
```

Comment: +1 for "disjunction" and "conjunction". Those are terms from my days programming in assembly language that I'd forgotten.

Comment: @theTinMan Aha, in my case, I don't know much programming languages. I learned these words in English grammar class.

Answer (score 0):

> first evalute ARGV[0] and if it doesn't exist then read from "somefile.txt". My ques

You are correct. The `ARGV.shift || "somefile.txt"` expression will evaluate to `ARGV.shift` if it returns some non-falsy value, and `"somefile.txt"` otherwise. Some other examples:

```
puts nil   || "foo"  # => "foo"
puts "foo" || "bar"  # => "foo"
puts "foo" || nil    # => "foo"

puts "foo" || raise  # => "foo"
                     # and doesn't blow up, because the 'raise'
                     # is never evaluated
```

> can the && operator be also used here

Sure, but is arguably of less practical value. It might be clearer to use an `if` in that case:

```
puts foo && bar

# is the same as:
if foo
  puts bar
end

# or:
puts bar if foo
```

> does this concept of "passing this or this argument to a method in Ruby" has a name?

I'm not sure if it has any 'official' name, but I commonly see this pattern being called 'default value' or 'fallback value'.

Comment: I don't know. Seems like a reasonable answer, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

`||` is using for providing default values. `||` returns first "true" value. "True" value -- value that is interpreted as true boolean value in ruby. So first "true" value in the chain will be as the result of the expression. `&&` returns first "false" value. Complete analogy. But it does not have such graceful application.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the obvious Boolean operator functionality, `&&` can be used like you could in some languages such as JavaScript:

```
a = cond1 && cond2 && value     # a is now value if cond1 and cond2,
                                # else nil or false (depends on cond1 and cond2)
```

It's not very readable (IMHO) when assigning non-Boolean variables, but it works.